existance of a path that doesn't tuch an isotopy
Let $f_t :S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be an isotopy i.e. the function $F:[0,1]×S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $F(t,x)= f_t(x)$ is continous, and each $f_t$ is homeomorphism onto it's image.
let $\alpha \not \in Im(f_0)$ I want to prove the existance of a continous path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\gamma(t) \not \in Im(f_t)$ and $\gamma(0) = α$
Μy motivation is to prove that isotopy preseve the index(or winding number) of two isotopic inclusions of $S^1$ By starting in the inside of ine of the inclusions and then
$wind(f_t, \gamma(t))$ should be a continous function into $\{1,-1\}$ and thus constant priving the claim.
Unfortanitly I am unable to prove the existance of such a path, looking for an hint or a full answer

Your question is unclear, starting with "Let $\alpha\notin Im(f_t)$": Do you mean that $t$ is fixed here or do you mean that $\alpha\notin Im(F)$? There are similar problems elsewhere in the text. The origin of the problem is your sloppy conflation of $f_t$ and $F$ in the very first sentence.

I am sorry I meant $f_0$

You should edit your question. Also, English sentences start with an upper case letter and end with a punctuation mark (usually the period, sometimes with the question mark or exclamation).

Now, look for similar issues with $f_t$ elsewhere in your post.
